# Call WebMethod asynchronously using semaphore and timeout in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, semaphore, webmethod

I am new to web based C# programming and asynchronous WebMethod calling. I have read couple of articles but does not find any effective way.

What can be done if I have 100's of web service method call and I want to call asynchronously 10 methods simultaneously among them. Wait for 5000 milliseconds for each WebMethod to response, provide timeout if response does not arrive in 5000 milliseconds and based on the semaphore releases from that 10 calls, I will call new methods from rest of the WebMethod.

what is the best way to implement this kind of scenario?

Sample:
I have shown 1 sample method only, but this way I have to call 100s of methods asynchronously.

```
     SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0,10);
    
    //Register method
    soapClient.MethodNameCompleted += soapClient_MethodNameCompleted;
    
    //Call method async
    MethodNameAsync();
    Semaphore.Wait()
    
//This method calls only when WebMethod send a response
    void soapClient_MethodNameCompleted(object sender, MethodNameCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                string result = e.Result.ToString();
                Semaphore.Release();
            }
```

Comment: mmm, `SemaphoreSlim` is about controlling thread access. I don't think you want to do this...could be wrong but unsure. `Asynchronously`  and `Simultaneously` are two different things. By default "Web Method" are each preformed on their own thread, allocated by the thread pool. So the better question is, why are you wanting to limit your web service to only be able to handle 10 requests at a time, apposed to... as fast as the machine can process them (100s). The reason I posed it like that is I think your understanding may be off.

Comment: @Seabizkit, I want only 10 requests at a time instead of 100, because if I do all 100 requests together, server will be unresponsive. So, by requesting 10 requests concurrently to server, it may give response faster. For that, I want to control 10 threads using `SemaphoreSlim` and once thread is free to do other task, I will provide new request to thread. So, I will have always 10 thread running `Asynchronously`.
Also, out of 10 threads, if any of the thread/request take more than specified time (i.e. 5000ms), I want to give timeout, release `SemaphoreSlim` and assign thread to new request.

Answer (score 0):

May be middleware help you. For example:

```csharp
public class SemaphoreMiddleware
{
    private readonly static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10, 10);

    private readonly RequestDelegate nextMiddleware;

    public SemaphoreMiddleware(RequestDelegate nextMiddleware)
    {
        this.nextMiddleware = nextMiddleware;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(stoppingToken);
        try
        {
            await nextMiddleware(httpContext);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

ASP.NET Core Middleware https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I guess, middleware is something that runs in a synchronous way and we should use it, when A depends on B, B depends on C, C depends on D and so on...
A >> B >> C >> D, and then if we want to execute D >> C >> B  >> A to get the response back.

But in my case, I want something that runs asynchronously and we can control the multiple threads by putting timeout for response.